# Triangle inequality for $\sqrt{x^T\cdot A\cdot x}$

Tags: normed-spaces

I want to prove that $f(x):= \sqrt{x^TAx}$ is a norm, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ positive definite, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I already proved its positivity and absolute homogeneity, but I don't know how to prove the triangle inequality:

$f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$

I started with

$\sqrt{(x+y)^TA(x+y)}$ = $\sqrt{(x^T+y^T)A(x+y)}$

but I don't know how to go on. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you instead prove that $(\rm x,\rm y)\mapsto \rm x^TAy$ is an inner product and thus conclude that $(\rm x,\rm x)\mapsto \sqrt{\rm x^TAx}$ is a norm.

Comment: Try proving a Cauchy-Schwartz inequality first

Comment: Yes, Git Gud's advice is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much :) To proof that it is an inner product was indeed the easier way.

Comment: @user2668777 No problem. It's recommended that you write up an answer yourself so this question doesn't come up as unanswered.